# Create and add object to RealmList in RealmMigration

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

In my current app, I have a `HolderObject` (which extends `RealmObject`) with a `long` 'machineId'. In a new version of the app, this `HolderObject` will be able to contain more machines, in the form of a RealmList. See the classes below:

Old object:

```
public class HolderObject extends RealmObject{
    private long machineId;
    //.. getters and setters
}
```

New object:

```
public class HolderObject extends RealmObject{
    private RealmList<RealmLong> machineIds;
    //.. getters and setters
}
```

In which `RealmLong` is as follows:

```
public class RealmLong extends RealmObject {
    private long val;
    //.. getters and setters
}
```

To migrate all old `HolderObject`s to the new objects, I use my custom RealmMigration. This is as follows:

```
public class CustomRealmMigration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        schema.get("HolderObject")
                .addRealmListField("machineIds", schema.get("RealmLong"))
                .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        RealmLong realmLong = realm.createObject(RealmLong.class);
                        realmLong.setVal(obj.getLong("machineId"));
                        obj.getList("machineIds").add(realmLong);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                        realm.close();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**Question:**

- In the line `obj.getList("machineIds").add(realmLong);`, I get the error that this function expects a `DynamicRealmObject`, not a `RealmLong`. How can I add a `RealmLong` to this list?
- *(Bonus question)* Is this the correct and best approach to this migration problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
schema.get("HolderObject")
        .addRealmListField("machineIds", schema.get("RealmLong"))
        .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
            @Override
            public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                DynamicRealmObject realmLong = realm.createObject("RealmLong");
                realmLong.setLong("val", obj.getLong("machineId"));
                obj.getList("machineIds").add(realmLong);
            }
        })
        .removeField("machineId");
```

The realmLong object you create has to be a DynamicRealmObject.
Also don't forget to remove the old field after the transformation.

Note that migrations are already wrapped in a transaction, you do not need to instantiate a realm object and execute a transaction yourself.

> (Bonus question) Is this the correct and best approach to this migration problem?

Idea is good, execution is not. See above.

For additional information about migrations, see [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java) example on github, and the docs of course.